# NAT between two addresses of one network card

Tags: ip, nat, squid, local

Is it possible to setup NAT between two addresses, one the same network card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is called ["NAT on a stick"](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094430.shtml).